# Definition of CDF of discrete RV

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

In many different (serious and good) statistics books I find different definitions of CDF of a discrete RV. The difference is the equal sign at the index of the summation sign. The first is:

$$F(x) = P(X\leq x) = \sum_{x_i\leq x} p_i$$

whereas the second is:

$$F(x) = P(X < x)= \sum_{x_i< x} p_i$$

For most of my life I was convinced that *CDF is a function returning the probability that a RV will take a value not greater than x*, and therefore I am used to the first definition.

So which one is it?

Comment: I have never seen the second form in a text or reference book... can you please give a reference?

Comment: It's a matter of convention.  In some disciplines (especially engineering-related ones), the CDF is defined as $\Pr(X \ge x),$ for instance.  Thus there isn't going to be any "right" answer; the best we can hope for in an answer would be a survey of which disciplines tend to use which conventions.

Comment: [Probability and statistics in examples](https://ksiegarnia.pwn.pl/Rachunek-prawdopodobienstwa-i-statystyka-matematyczna-w-zadaniach-czesc-1,68738725,p.html) page 52

Comment: Very interesting, @whuber. I'm in engineering and only CDF definition I've seen is $P(X\le x)$. I've seen CCDF as $P(X > x)$.  I've scoured some common textbooks from various time periods. Mind if I ask what engineering fields?

Comment: @Secret Those involving reliability and failure.  I ran into this convention recently on a project concerning estimating the sizes of boulders: there, all interest focuses on the largest boulders, so some of the engineers involved take it for granted that distribution laws are written in terms of the CCDF (although they don't call it that).

Comment: @whuber, thanks for sharing. I didn't see that in my Reliability & Failure Analysis courses or books, but interesting to know it is out there.

Comment: @Secret Mathematically these distinctions are of no consequence.  We could study distributions using any of the conventions for CDFs.  After all, the CCDF of random variable $X$ is a simple transform of the CDF of $-X.$  Thus there aren't any conceptual issues raised.  Perhaps the most important thing worth knowing is that when you're reading unfamiliar literature, confirm your understanding of the conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is correct. For continuous RV's the distinction is meaningless, i.e. $P(X\leq x)=P(X<x)$, since the probability of observing a single value of the RV is zero, since a single point on the real line has Lebesgue measure of zero. With discrete RV's the distinction is important because $P(X\leq x) \neq P(X<x)$.

Comment: That is my opinion too. However, I can't understand how come such thing can be found in really decent books. What reference could I use to back that up?

Comment: In which textbook did you see this? Casella and Berger will certainly have it correct.